# How to make endermen die in one hit, without the use of fall damage?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built Ilmango's Endermen XP farm and its really fast. But one problem with the design is that the Endermen aren't one hit kills, unlike other (slower and larger) designs, since it doesn't drop the Endermen from a high place (since the lower the spawning platform is the more Endermen) to get them to half a heart. They require around 2 - 3 hits with a Sharpness V diamond sword (other designs only need a punch).

So, how can I reduce the health of them without using fall damage. They seem to teleport out of suffocation traps (which are anyways too slow) so is there a method other than fall damage to get them to half a heart?

Comment: I didn't understand why your question got a downvote. Would the downvoter care to elaborate?

Comment: I also don't understand why the downvote.

Comment: I can't be bothered to do the science of the amount of damage lava/fire does, or how many ticks of water an enderman can survive. I believe endermen do not teleport into water blocks and do not teleport an unlimited distance, which would allow you to create a timed trap.

Comment: @Sumurai8 won't they teleport back to the spawning platforms (maybe soul sand or snow can stop this).Also if you are creating a timed trapped it will have to be able to support about 10 endermen spawning second

Comment: You could simply spawn them with low health instead of trying to damage them. Just summon them with `{Attributes:[{Name:generic.maxHealth, Base:1.0}]}`

Comment: @dly I want to do this on a SMP server so no commands.

Answer (score 4):

So far, there isn't anything else possible to kill Endermen in one hit rather than fall damage. It isn't possible. I tried to test these things out, but none of them worked.

However, this doesn't mean that there is no way to kill Enderman in one hit 100%. If nothing is confirmed, then there is no possible way to do something like this.

Answer (score 1):

From the Minecraft Wiki:

> It is possible (but expensive) to kill an enderman in one hit, by using a diamond sword with the Sharpness V Enchantment, while also having the Strength II Effect active, and landing a critical hit.

Since I got clarification that you are looking for a mob-grinder, what you need to do is build your enderman farm way out into the void off of any End island, then cover every surface with blocks that stop their teleportation, such as water or lava. The spawning platforms would then be at least 32 blocks above where the killing chamber is, as that is the distance of teleporting (24 blocks vertical but 32 has been reported). You can then use a regular diamond sword at that point, or a suffocator or mob jammer since they have nowhere else to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sharpness 5 diamond sword, and hit them in the legs, because if you hit them in the legs they can't teleport away.

Comment: This is not an answer since I want to reduce to half a heart without the player involed.Also a Sharpness V requires about 5 hits on a enderman

Comment: Creative or survival?

Comment: If you do fall damage than it would be about 43 blocks that it would to fall

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need strength AND a Sharpness 5 diamond sword. Or you can use some commands to get strength or sharpness.

Sharpness item (1.8+)

`/give @p minecraft:(any item) 1 0 {Unbreakable:1,ench:[{id:16,lvl:16000}]}`

Strength

`/effect @p minecraft:strength (time in seconds) (level max is 255) true`

Comment: Strength is also 1.8+

Comment: will strenght II beacon and sharpness V diamond sword kill them in one hit ?

Answer (score -2):

putting the farm in the end and covering all available spawn spaces with water might work they can teleport only 32 blocks and the distance between end islands is something in the thousands